# creating jar using -C flag

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a Jar file from command line using -C flag, but every time it returns a help screen.
I am giving following command.

```
user@ubuntu:~/CDH/JAVA_WORKSPACE/JAVA-SETUP$ jar cvfm ./build/jar/Setup.jar MANIFEST -C build/classes/com/demo/Setup.class
```

If I remove -C command then it archives fine.
But if -C flag is there, then it always returns jar help page.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line option is:

```
-C build/classes/com/demo/Setup.class
```

The jar tools wants the directory name to follow the -C and then the file. You need two words to follow "-C" like this:

```
-C build/classes/com/demo Setup.class
```